# WP make post title active

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I have a simple website that displays every post title in a list, I'm trying to change the active post title to be different when its being viewed. I have tried this but it's not working.

```
<ul class="students">
 <?php

 $IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
 global $post;

 $myposts = wp_get_archives('type=alpha');
 foreach($myposts as $post) :
 ?>

      <li <?php if(is_single() && $IDOutsideLoop == $post->ID) print 'style="font-weight:bold";' 
      ?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

 <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: `$myposts = wp_get_archives('type=alpha');`...That shouldn't work at all.

Comment: rnevius, it gets the posts titles and puts them in alphabetical order

Comment: Worked with get_posts instead of wp_get_archives, thanks rnevius

Answer (score 0):

Worked with get_posts instead of wp_get_archives

```
<?php

global $post;
$IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 999, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($myposts as $post) :
?>

      <li <?php if(is_single() && $IDOutsideLoop == $post->ID) print 'class="viewing"'; ?>>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```